# Chicken programming hello world

Tags: esoteric-languages

For 'fun' I'm trying to understand the esoteric programming language [Chicken](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Chicken), but just can't seem to get it. The Hello World example is the one I'm trying to fully understand. Many sites refer to [torso.me/Chicken](http://torso.me/chicken), but that site, unfortunately, seems down.

Using the Hello World code available at Esolang, I have a few questions:
Q1:
At line 12, 13, and 14 there are 10, 17, and 3 chickens. This means I think that 0 will be pushed on the stack, then 7 will be pushed, and then the top two values of the stack will be subtracted from each other, but since we pushed 0 and 7, that will be 7 - 0 = 7. Couldn't line 12 and 14 simply be removed, or am I completely wrong in the interpretation?

Q2:
At line 57 there are 8 chickens. So a jump statement. But for a jump statement, only if the condition on the next line is true. The next line has 11 chicken so simply pushes 1 which I assume will always be true, wouldn't this mean it will simply keep looping?

Q3:
I think I'm not understanding something fundamentally. Below a simple example code and what I'd expect the program than to do:

```
12 Chickens = Push 2 => Stack (bottom to top) => 2
15 Chickens = Push 5 => Stack (bottom to top) => 2 - 5
4 Chickens = multiply => Stack (bottom to top) => 10
11 Chickens = Push 1 => Stack (bottom to top) => 10 - 1
6 Chickens = Load next instructions 0 loads from stack
10 Chickens so load from stack top of stack points to stack index => 10 - 1 - 10
15 Chickens = Push 5 => Stack (bottom to top) => 10 - 1 - 10 - 5
12 Chickens = Push 2 => Stack (bottom to top) => 10 - 1 - 10 - 5 - 2
7 Chickens = Store => Stack (bottom to top) => 10 - 5 - 10 - 2
43 Chickens = Push 33 => Stack (bottom to top) => 10 - 5 - 10 - 2 - 33
9 Chickens = char => Stack (bottom to top) => 10 - 5 - 10 - 2 - 33 - !
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please remove the `chicken-scheme` flag? It's not an esoteric programming language at all and an entirely different beast compared to what you describe.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Thought I only typed 'chicken' but seems to have auto-suggest it to chicken-scheme. Have removed it.